# Trigger-Series of tables, update all except last which will update along with old values

Tags: php, mysql, database, easyphp

I'm putting together a series of identical tables that consist of only dates submitted to DB. The dates mark when a particular job was executed.

The tables work like dominoes in that when a date is submitted in the update table/form the next table assumes the old date through a BEFORE UPDATE trigger, and so on, and so on.

Each of these tables can be linked from the update table, and the point of them is to view a history of work performed, when a particular job was executed. After 20 or so tables the older dates become somewhat irrelevant, but should all be eventually archived in a final, 21st table which absorbs all the dates that keep getting updated.

This last table is updated via trigger but the old dates/values should be kept, maybe separated by comma. In other words while tables 1-20 contain only one date/entry per field, the overwritten date from the previous table, table 21 will list ALL the dates associated with that particular field that have been, or will be passed down, so no OLD values are overwritten.

After extensive research I discoverted that INSERT does not overwrite old data, but every attempt at writing a trigger with INSERT to this last table has failed. All tables have the same ID-"1". No new tables are created, this is a simple exercise in storing data, and yet this last method is elusive.

No previous answers on SO really helped. How to do this simple job?
The UPDATE trigger that works, one derived from a previous SO question, for all the other tables, looks something like this:

```
 BEGIN
  UPDATE work2 SET 
 ins1 = OLD.ins1,
 insp1 = OLD.insp1,
 b1psp = OLD.b1psp,
 b1ptp = OLD.b1ptp,
 ..........................etc
 WHERE work2.id = OLD.id; 
 END
```

There must be a simple solution, yet I'm not familiar with PHP enough to solve this. I'm using EasyPHP DevServer 14.1.

Comment: This sounds exactly why triggers have such a bad name. I can understand and appreciate triggers to archive "historical" data from a table A to a table A_history, or log changes to table A in another table; but why would you need 21 layers of that?!

Comment: Your first sentence is suspicious.  A series of identical tables often indicates a data modelling problem.

Comment: This a work in development. It's just where I'm at right now. The customer might also say that, and I'll promptly remove all tables 2-20, but right now I just need the method of storing all old data, using INSERT where a compilation of that data is stored for the time being

Comment: You have a customer and this is your initial design? If you need to store old data, why are you (re)moving it from the table?  That said, and I can't find any references, I seem to recall that (at least at one time) MySQL triggers could only cause other triggers to execute so "deep"; it was a crude solution to prevent trigger execution chains being infinite loops. ...but I could be thinking of foreign key cascading.

Comment: @uueerdo I need the first, updateable table/form to be just that. It's a table with 400+fields, and not all dates on the table are changed, the table represents the most recent dates of work performed, the second the previous instance, and so on..The data modelling may not be perfect, but you're all straying from the point, I think. I hope this helps.